# Sort Data on react-firebase-hooks/database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

So in React, I'm reading a firebase real-time database using the `"react-firebase-hooks/database"` package.

```
import { useList } from "react-firebase-hooks/database";
import { db, auth } from "../../firebase";

function GameHistory() {
  var dbRef = db.ref("/" + user.uid);

  const [snapshots, loading, error] = useList(dbRef);
```

So basically snapshots variable contains all the firebase realtime database data.
Then later in my code I simply map each element of the snapshot array into a component.

Here is the problem, I want to sort my snapshots data in order of the `.timestamp` firebase property in my data. I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried to sort the snapshot data when I map it:

```
snapshots
            .sort((a, b) => {
              return a.val().timestamp > b.val().timestamp;
            })
            .map((game, index) => (MORE CODE
```

But that doesn't work because timestamp is a firebase object, and JavaScript doesn't know what to do with it.

Just to establish more context on the timestamp variable, I defined it as such:

`timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

So is there any way to sort my snapshot data? Or should I use another package? If I should use something else please show code for how you read and sort the realtime db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two different databases here:

- The `import { useList } from "react-firebase-hooks/database"` and other code are for the Realtime Database.
- The `timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is for Cloud Firestore

While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and each has their own API.

To write a server-side timestamp to Realtime Database, use:

```
timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

I'd actually also let the database server handle the sorting, instead of doing this in your code, which is done with:

```
var dbRef = db.ref("/" + user.uid);
const dbQuery = dbRef.orderByChild("timestamp");

const [snapshots, loading, error] = useList(dbQuery);
...
```

Comment: Thank You! I updated the timestamp stuff. Also when I ran the code it says that `this.Ref.orderBy is not a function`, I did some googling, but does `.orderByChild` do the same thing? Also if I want to sort it in descending order how would I do that? I tried `.orderBy("timestamp", "desc")`, but that didn't work. Do you recommend I just reverse the array locally in JS?

Comment: Oops, the `orderBy` was a typo, should be `orderByChild`. There is no descending sort in Firebase, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+descending